# VBA failing with array or user defined type expected

Tags: arrays, vba, vb.net

I have some code I am moving from VB.NET to VBA which has worked in the .NET world quite well. I have successfully moved almost all of the code into the VBA world with one exception thus far. Here is much of the code in question and all the variable declarations`

```
Dim vault As IEdmVault14
Dim eFile As IEdmFile9
Dim eFolder As IEdmFolder7
Dim pos As IEdmPos5
Dim Pathlist As EdmStrLst5
Dim parentFolder As IEdmFolder5
Dim vaultName As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim AssyName As String
Dim LoggedIn As Boolean

Set EdmVault5 = New EdmVault5

Set vault = New EdmVault5Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim sw As TextStream
    Set sw = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\temp\" & AssyName & ".txt")

    '-----------------------------GET COLUMN HEADERS
    Dim columns() As EdmBomColumn

    BOM.GetColumns columns

    Dim header As String

    header = "LEVEL" & vbTab

    Dim column As EdmBomColumn

    For i = 0 To UBound(columns)
        header = header & columns(i).mbsCaption & vbTab
    Next
    sw.writeline (header)


    '-----------------------------Bom.READ EACH BOM ROW

    Dim rows As Object
    Dim row As IEdmBomCell
    BOM.GetRows (rows)


    For i = 0 To UBound(rows)
        If IsNothing(row) Then Exit For
        Dim rowString As String
        Set rowString = row.GetTreeLevel.ToString & vbTab
        Dim varVal As String
        varVal = ""

        For i = 0 To UBound(columns)
            row.GetVar(column.mlVariableID, column.meType, varVal, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
            If IsNothing(varVal) Then varVal = ""
            rowString = rowString & varVal & vbTab
        Next
        '-----------------------------WRITE THE ROW TO THE FILE
       sw.writeline (rowString)
    Next
    sw.Close
```

`

The array error occurs at BOM.GetRows (rows). I am stuck on what the issue could be. This error code does not occur in VB.NET but .NET does warn that Variable 'rows' is passed by reference before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. I am not clear on how that translates into VBA if at all.

If anyone could shed some light on this it would be helpful I'm sure.

Comment: What type is `BOM`?  Is it defined in a referenced type library?  If so, open the "Object Explorer" (View Menu->Object Explorer) and look up the method `GetRows` to see what type it expects.  Also remove the "(" and ")" from around `rows` in the method call in VBA.

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem... an array is expected.  I notice the `GetColumns` call is passing an array, would this not also be the case for `GetRows`?

Comment: Try removing the parentheses around `rows`.

Comment: In the Object Explorer for GetRows the it states the following. GetRows(ppoRows() As Variant)
    Member of EdmLib.EdmBomView
    method GetRows

I have tried removing the parens around rows and no luck. I tried also dim Rows as variant. No luck.

Comment: I have changed the code to the following:

Dim rows() As Variant
Dim row As IEdmBomCell
BOM.GetRows rows

Seems happy at the moment but I have another snag. Is Object in VB.NET analogous to a Variant in VBA?

Comment: In VBA, and Object data type holds a pointer to the object (32 bit address, i think). So it can hold any object. A Variant can hold anything, including and object. The Variant data type was created, in part, because Excel cells can hold numbers, text, dates, and errors, and they needed something to handle any of those.

Comment: An array isn't an Object in that you can't store a pointer. Well, you probably can, but it's not how it's normally done. A Variant can hold an array, but it won't be recognized as an array until you store one in it. So if you pass a Variant into a function that expects an array, it will fail.

Comment: @DickKusleika it's [4 bytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary), i.e. 32 bits indeed.

Comment: Ah ha, subtle but important point. Good insight.

Comment: So, what is your question? We need to see the line with error - not the calling of procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method signature (or function signature or whatever) that requires an array, then you have to `Dim` the variable you pass in as an array.

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim x As Variant

    Debug.Assert Not IsArray(x)

    x = Array(1, 2)

    Debug.Assert IsArray(x)

    GetStuff x 'this fails

    Stop

End Sub


Public Function GetStuff(a() As Variant) As Double

    GetStuff = 1

End Function
```

Even though a Variant can hold an array, it doesn't pass the `IsArray` test just by declaring it. If I assign an array to it, it passes `IsArray`, but I still can't use it as an argument to function that requires an array. `x` is a Variant array and `a()` is an array of Variants. So the above code still won't compile.

It sounds from your comments that you got it sorted, but I thought I'd throw a little more information out there for posterity.